# Java program to separate an integer

Tags: java, integer

I've written the following code in Java to separate an integer. Example: 12345 to 1 2 3 4 5

Here is the code:

```
public class Modulus {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    String counter= Integer.toString(number);
    int count=(int)(counter.length()-1);
```

Comment: is this homework?  If so tag it as such.

Answer (score 3):

You want `counter.length()` not `counter.length()-1`, when you create the array.  The indexes of the array goes to `n-1`, not the length of the string (which is `n`).

When you loop thru the array, you want to start at `count-1`, and go down from there.

If the number is `12345`, then your array needs to be of size `5`, to hold the 5 digits, and the indexes go from `0-4`.   Accordingly, you want to create the array with `count`, and start printing at `count-1`.

That should address your index out of bounds issue, but you have other issues too.

Note your loop will stop as soon as it finds a zero, even if its in the middle of the digits.  So if you have 3405, your app will print 5 and then stop.

Also, the comments to your question hint at overall simpler approaches, although what you are doing is fine for learning.

Comment: But wouldn't that make the array size one to big? I tried it though, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: the counter.length-1 gives an array of the wrong length, its the track[count]= that causes the exception, the count needs to be decremented before the setting of the array not at the end of the loop

Comment: @user1213994, no, I added text to explain that (3rd paragraph)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I managed to fix it. I edited the post with the fix because it doesn't fit in the comments and I can't answer my own question yet

Answer (score 0):

Coming out of the first while loop you'll have count>=0 evaluating to false - count will be negative.

Going into the second while loop, you're trying to evaluate track[count]. If count is negative, this will throw the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

**Edit:** as pointed out by hvgotcodes - the exception you're seeing is actually being thrown earlier in the code.

```
int [] track = new int[count];   // int of length count - indexed 0 to count-1

    while (num > 0 && count>=0) {
        track[count]=(num % 10); // get value indexed count - out of bounds!
```

Once this is resolved, you may run into the issue I've spotted. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from zero.
 So if you do int count=(int)(counter.length()-1);
 if suppose your count is 3, you can have indexes 0, 1, 2
 When you write  track[count]=(num % 10), you trying track[3] and thus you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
counter.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 ")
```

It will replace each character with the character+ a sapce.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public class Modulus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numString = "12345";
        int num = Integer.parseInt(numString);
        char[] numCharArray = numString.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<numCharArray.length;i++){
            System.out.print(numCharArray[i]+i != numCharArray.length-1 ? " " : "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: giving the answer is not the best idea for people doing homework trying to learn.